# How do I remove a word that contains special characters

Tags: python, string, list

I am new to python. I need help figuring out how do I remove a word from a list of strings that contains special characters?

x = ["I", "@prerkls", "saw"]

How do I remove the word that contain the @ sign?

Comment: What have you already researched or tried; and why is it not working as desired? Perhaps consider the `string` library or using regex, as available in the `re` library.

Answer (score 0):

The below will remove the non-desirable words from the original list of words (mutates the input list).

```
def remove(words, special):
    wr_idx = 0 # effectively the new size of the modified list
    for curr_idx in range(len(words)):
        if special in words[curr_idx]: # remove by not copying back
            continue
        words[wr_idx] = words[curr_idx]
        wr_idx += 1
    
    del words[wr_idx:]
```

For your case we'd do:

```
x = ["I", "@prerkls", "saw"]
remove(x, '@')
print(x)
```

Output

```
['I', 'saw']
```

Comment: Actually you could invert a condition (`in` -> `not in`) and put all further code under condition (removing `continue` call).